# Difference between these implementations in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

In Linux kernel code, I can see the macro which expands to

```
(1<<0)
```

What does it imply? We can directly use 1 in that place why (1<<0)?

Basically what is the difference between

```
(AVIVO_D1CRTC_CONTROL & (1<<0))
```

and

```
(AVIVO_D1CRTC_CONTROL & (1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does it imply? We can directly use 1 in that place why (1<<0)?

The bit-shift is consistent with the Boolean expression it is in.
This is not an arithmetic expression, and the numeric value of this literal constant is not salient.
What is salient is to convey the quantity of bits and the bit position(s) employed in this bit-masking operation.

You are unfortunately citing a degenerate case which does not demonstrate the advantage (in a logical expression) of using a bit-shift over the numeric value .
Admittedly it is easier to type, read, and comprehend `1` than `(1 << 0)`.
But now that 32-bit processors and devices are ubiquitous, the larger registers and their bit definitions & bit masks will involve high powers of two.
So even though every programmer should know the bit values of a byte (i.e. the first eight powers of two), how many can do the same up to 2^31?

IOW which of the following macros is easiest to understand which bit is being defined?

```
#define AVIVO_CRTC_DISP_READ_REQUEST_DISABLE             16777216
#define AVIVO_CRTC_DISP_READ_REQUEST_DISABLE             0x1000000
#define AVIVO_CRTC_DISP_READ_REQUEST_DISABLE             (1 << 24)
```

---

Devices have control and status bits accessed through registers.  The device datasheets have register descriptions that map out the bits in each register.
The modern convention is to number the register bits right to left starting with zero (like the powers of two in a binary number).
These control and status bits in the registers are often identified by the bit number, so incorporating this bit number in its definition (using a bit shift expression) is practical and more efficient than converting it to a numeric value.
It is then very easy to correlate these register diagrams with the macros for the bit definitions that use bit shifts.

---

> Basically what is the difference between

In terms of generated object code: no difference.
To the compiler: the macro substitution and evaluation of the expression requires a trivial amount of extra compile time.
For readability and maintainability of the code: the bit-shift is the preferred choice.

Comment: Thanks @sawdust :) Dont know why the question was voted down

Comment: *"Dont know why the question was voted down"* -- Maybe someone thinks the answer is "obvious".  I just assumed that you may have a microcontroller background (where code readability is rarely practiced) or are simply inexperienced, especially with hardware and drivers.

Comment: …and we have `BIT()` macro for most of use cases.

Answer (score 0):

It's a style thing.

```
(X & (1<<0)) // And X with a value that has the 0th bit set.
```

which expands much nicer for

```
(X & (1<<7)) // And X with a value that has the 7th bit set.
```

vice

```
(X & (1)) // And X with 1.

(X & (128)) // And X with 128. (or 0x80)
```

Edit: Because I screwed up the manual bit shifts... Second edit I had it right the first time.

Comment: Since the question was tagged with `linux-kernel`, any code examples in an answer should conform to Linux kernel coding style, i.e. no C99- style comments.  Linux style for comments is the C89 "/* ... */" style

Comment: I was unaware of that rule. I would hardly call the above a code example. The code blocks were mainly used to improve readability. Is there a place where all of the rules about different tags are written down? Clever that you gave me a comment about my style when my response was all about style.